# Update DynamoDB table from another stack in AWS CDK

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cdk

I'm looking for a TypeScript code to update DynamoDB created in one stack from another stack by using lambda and API gateway. Both stacks are in the same environment. Please advice, if this is doable.

Comment: Do you mind sharing what is your goal for trying to do this?

Comment: To clarify, you are just updating the item in the table, not the table definition, am I correct? And what have you tried and what challenges you faced? Please update this information in the question. Normally you should be able to do so using mostly the same way you can update a table in the same stack.

Comment: Correct, I want to add or update item in the table but the table require to access from different stacks such as a stack handling input request needs to add item in the table as pending status and another stack which gets response back needs to update the item. basically I want to keep DynamoDB table stack separate which can be access by other stacks those are handling other functions. Hope this clarifies above both questions. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding of your requirement:  you previously deployed a CDK App with a DynamoDB table (let's call the App's Stack `DynamoStack`).  Now you have a new stack - say, `APIStack` - with an API Gateway backed by a Lambda target.  How does your `APIStack` get access to the table from `DynamoStack` so your Lambda can read/write to the table?

#### Prefer a Multi-Stack App

Ideally, you would add `APIStack` to the App that has your `DynamoStack`.  It's generally good to group related stacks in a single CDK App.  If you do so, it's trivial to pass resources between stacks.  Just export the `dynamodb.Table` as a class field from `DynamoStack` and pass it to to `APIStack` as a prop.

#### Separate Apps

If for some reason grouping the Stacks in a single App is not feasible, wiring up cross-stack references takes a few more steps.

In `DynamoStack`, create a CloudFormation output, whose Export Name can be imported into the other stacks:

```js
// DynamoStack.ts
new cdk.CfnOutput(this, 'TableArn', { value: table.tableArn, exportName: 'DemoTableArn' });
```

In `APIStack`, make a [ITable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_dynamodb.ITable.html) reference using the imported ARN.   Use it to set the Lambda env var and give the lambda read-write access to the table:

```js
// ApiStack.ts
const tableArn = cdk.Fn.importValue('DemoTableArn');
const table: dynamodb.ITable = dynamodb.Table.fromTableArn(this, 'ITable', tableArn);

const func = new nodejs.NodejsFunction(this, 'MyHandlerFunction', {
  entry: path.join(__dirname, 'func.ts'),
  environment: {
    TABLE_NAME: cdk.Arn.extractResourceName(tableArn, 'table'),
  },
});

table.grantReadWriteData(func);
```

Comment: Thank you, Fedonev! Your suggestion is perfect, it works fine for me.